# Python Methods: optional arguments and commas

Tags: python

The signature of the python index method is `list.index(x[, start[, end]])`.  (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

I understand that optional arguments are enclosed in square brackets but am unsure how to interpret the commas?

Why couldn't the signature of this method be more simply represented as

`list.index(x, [start], [end])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.index(x, [start], [end])
```

Suggests that the commas are not part of the optional elements. It suggests that the following are valid:

```
list.index(1, , )
list.index(1, 2, )
list.index(1, , 3)
```

Which obviously aren't valid.

You lose the nested square brackets that tell you that end only makes sense if start is specified.